# How to convert a data column of class "list" to class "numeric"

Tags: r, dataframe, type-conversion

My data frame's name is `kineticsData` and the data column I'm trying to convert is `kineticsData$cellUptake`

When I run

```
sapply(kineticsData, class)
```

I get the following result for the data column of interest

```
cellUptake
"factor"
```

I looked through a lot of old questions on here and I tried to convert my data column to `"numeric"` using their advice, but after running

```
as.numeric(levels(kineticsData$cellUptake))[kineticsData$cellUptake]
```

However, I still see

```
cellUptake
"factor"
```

after running `sapply` again. Can anyone help me figure out what's going on?

Also, I'm wondering if part of the problem is the fact that I'm importing the data in from an excel file where I've filled in the blank cells with a dash symbol: `-`

I noticed that the columns with numerical values but without any blank `-` cells automatically are imported as `"numeric"`

Comment: `as.numeric(as.character(kineticsData$cellUptake))`

Comment: it's hard to know exactly what will work for your data if you don't share a little bit of it. `as.numeric(unlist(kineticsData$cellUptake))` may help you, you could also try to specify column classes when you read in the data

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is with the dash -  symbol.  Try replacing all of the - with NA or leave it blank.  Since - isn't a number, it can't convert that column to numeric.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try it later to see if it works, and if it does I'll give you the green checkmark.